# Finding first and last occurrence

Tags: python

I am working on a practice problem about tracking and recording occurrences in a loop then return them when the loop is over. I have to loop through pixel colors of a simple image along Y axis like this one:

[image: example pic]

This is my code:

```
for y in range(0, Img.size[1]):
    x=0
    color = spImg.getpixel((x, y))
    print(color)
```

For this exercise I will always have the RGB values to the two different colors. I am looking for some elegant insights on storing information during a loop. The goal for me is to create a function that returns the y position of the top and bottom of the red section of the provided image.

I did come up with solutions like adding colors to a list with a counter and use `list[-1]` to track changes or parse the list after the color detection loop is over.

But all my solutions just seem very clunky and I think there is room for logic improvement.

Edit: just realized I only have partial solution like this

```
colorList = []
for y in range(0, Img.size[1]):
    x=0
    color = spImg.getpixel((x, y))
    colorList.append(color)
firstOccurrence = colorList.index(redColor)#only first occurrence
```

Comment: I think you should add to the question what you have tried so far and explain better what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You could use a dictionary.

Comment: You need to be more specific and precise with your question: you are recording occurrences of what? Storing what information? What solutions have you tried? what output do you need?

Comment: hey yes i realize i wasnt specific at all.  The goal for me is to create a function that returns the y position of the top and bottom of the red section of the provided image. also added this to my question

Comment: You could keep track of the previous pixel's value and compare to the current one, then just store the actual transitions in a list. This is basically isomorphic to run-length encoding.

Answer (score 0):

ok by htting some rocks together i have come up with a solution. Probably not thoe most effective but at least i feel somewhat satisfied with.

```
clrs = []
tarClrList = []
for y in range(0, Img.size[1]):
    x=0
    color = Img.getpixel((x, y))
    clrs.append(color)
    if color == green:
        tarClrList.append(clrs.index(green,y))
max = tarClrList[-1]
min = tarClrList[0]
```